# I do not understand why `what /bin/sh` and `/bin/sh --version` do not agree on macOS Big Sur

Tags: command-line

On macOS Big Sur, I get

```
$ what /bin/sh
/bin/sh
    PROGRAM:sh  PROJECT:dash-11
    PROGRAM:sh  PROJECT:dash-11
```

```
$ /bin/sh --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin20)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

It seems that `/bin/sh` is actually `bash` and not `dash`. Why is `what` saying differently?

Comment: From `man what`: **what** -- show what versions of object modules were used to construct a file -- I take that to mean it's just part of the picture, so to speak, and not the whole picture.

Comment: Having a quick look at apple open source page and what. It just does a simple search for @(#) - I can see where the old expected sccsid is set but that is now commented out I think some Xcode trickery adds this line now

Comment: As for dash  I can't see it in the Apple open Source release https://opensource.apple.com/release/macos-115.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/bin/sh` is a wrapper that forwards to another shell. If the link `/private/var/select/sh` is present, the shell pointed to by this link is started. Otherwise, one of fallbacks (bash, dash, or zsh) is executed.

So if your `/private/var/select/sh` points to `/bin/bash`, that's what eventually gets executed when you run `/bin/sh --version`.

See also `man sh` where this is described.

It seems this wrapper is indeed from the dash project (or at least Apple's version; couldn't find the source they're using), which is why `what` reports `dash-11`.

Comment: I can't see the wrapper in the original dash https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/dash/dash.git/  and what sets the link?

Comment: @mmmmmm: It looks like this an Apple-specific addition. Unfortunately, they don't publish their version on opensource.apple.com.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `what`, the program looks through the binary `/bin/sh` searching for a specific text pattern. This specific text pattern was put there by a source code revision control system named SCCS, that is used to keep track of changes to source code. The idea was that SCCS automatically updated a text string within the source code to contain a version marker that would then end up in the finished program. The `what` command could then be used to figure out which version of the source code that was used for building a specific binary.

Today, SCCS is considered ancient - being designed in the early 70s and not is not really used by anyone anymore (except perhaps for software archaeology). Therefore you can commonly find that programs that contain code dating back a long while might have such a text pattern inserted decades ago that hasn't been updated since or requires manual updating.

Basically you cannot really be sure that `what` outputs something that is actually "true".

In particular case it is so that `sh` is often a reduced version of a shell program (in comparison to for example a full blown `bash` shell). For example on the Mac I'm using right now, `sh` is 31 kB binary, where for example `bash` comes in at 609 kB and `dash` at 108 kB.

It is common to see that `sh` is a stripped down version of some other shell, or only a "bare-bones" shell. It is also common to see that other shells, such as for example `bash` offers a mode where they can be used to replace `sh` by simulating a simpler shell. In addition you can have a small, simple `sh` that calls out to a larger shell binary (like `bash`) when complexity is needed.

Earlier on macOS, `sh` was basically just `bash` run in compatibility mode. However, `bash` is a quite large program. On the other hand `dash` can also function as a simple `sh` shell, and is more light-weight. In order to get compatibility between versions, you can have `dash` simply respond to --version as `bash` would have done, behave like `sh` would have done - all while being a `dash` binary.

Comment: I understand everything you are writing.
But why would `what` return `dash`? `dash` was not even present on macOS a few years ago.

Comment: `what` returns text strings that are present in a binary.  That's all.  It doesn't have anything to do with whether some **other** binary exists that might be named the same as a substring of the text `what` returns.  You are reading **way** too much into it.

Comment: @DamienL `what` just reads the binary file and finds the special marker left behind by SCCS. The string "dash" doesn't come from `what` itself, it is read from inside `sh`. The `sh` binary contains the string "@(#)PROGRAM:sh  PROJECT:dash-11".

Comment: Now the only thing that means is that the developer had a variable with that string in it in the program. He might have started with source code from dash and stripped it down, he might have just thrown it in there with cut-n-paste - or he might have meant something entirely different by "dash". The `sh` program itself contains strings that identify /bin/bash, /bin/dash and /bin/zsh as those are the three shells it can startup to simulate sh.